# Can't Understand Security concept in REST API

Tags: rest, api, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft graph API. I successfully used token authentication. In order to download a file, I make a request (with token in header) to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{item_id_here}/ to then get an @microsoftgraph_downloadurl. Then I can ajax to this url without any authorization header, and the documentation states that this link is only temporary.

My question is, even though the link is temporary, isn't this still very insecure? Why can't I just write a script to test random @microsoftgraph_downloadurls until it hits one just in that time window and I steal someone's document?

Is the algorithm relying on the size of the random space of the generated url as a security measure?

Answer (score 0):

They have mechanisms in place to prevent brute forcing (or guessing the link).

And the link is only valid for a certain time, so they probably encode the maximum timespan in the url.

Answer (score 0):

The token you obtain from the auth context is only valid for the Office 365 tenant the app is registered for. And if obtained by your user, the token will not only be limited to your access within the tenant, but your user will probably the one that will leave thumbprints all-over. It would not seem smart to do that within your own organization.

Most permissions is also something that needs an admin consent to get access to. And if this is a multi-tenant app, almost all requests needs an admin consent.

And if you are not obtaining the access token by your user, but as "app context" instead of delegated access, it would be fairly easy to trace it back to you.

Also: The address provided https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{item_id_here}/ contains "/me" and you will only attempt to steal your own documents or documents you already have access to in OneDrive :-)